# Discriminant finding program

Tags: java, quadratic

Basically, I'm trying to write a program that gives you the discriminant of a quadratic equation with three variables. However when I try to create an object that has the a b and c values of my quadratic it says I didn't create the object. Also I'm new, so if I did something obviously wrong forgive me.

This is the Error I get.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: 
    at quadratic.equation.solver.QuadraticEquationSolver.main(QuadraticEquationSolver.java:38)
Java Result: 1

Below is the code.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package quadratic.equation.solver;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class QuadraticEquationSolver {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    class Quadratic {

        int aValue;
        int bValue;
        int cValue;

        public Quadratic(int A, int B, int C) {
            aValue = A;
            bValue = B;
            cValue = C;
        }

        public int calculateDiscriminant(int A, int B, int C) {
            int answer = ((bValue*bValue)+(-4*aValue*cValue));
            return answer;
        }

        Quadratic firstQuad = new Quadratic(7, 5, 3); 

     } 
     System.out.println(firstQuad.calculateDiscriminant);
}
```

Comment: this compiles? firstQuad exist in main context? ..

Answer (score 1):

This is more clear solution.

```
public class Quadratic {


    private int aValue;
    private int bValue;
    private int cValue;

   //constructor
   public Quadratic(int a, int b, int c) {
      aValue = a;
      bValue = b;
      cValue = c;
    }

  public int calculateDiscriminant() {
    int answer = ((bValue*bValue)+(-4*aValue*cValue));
    return answer;
  }

}//end class
```

And now a test class.

```
public class Test{    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Quadratic firstQuad = new Quadratic(7, 5, 3); 
        System.out.println(firstQuad.calculateDiscriminant());

    } 

}
```

Or Just

```
public final class MathUtil {

private MathUtil(){}

 public static int calculateQuadraticDiscriminant(int aValue,int bValue, int cValue) {
        return ((bValue*bValue)+(-4*aValue*cValue));        
 }

}
```